# How to validate data types in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have been trying to validate the data type of the data that I got from a flat file through pig.

A simple CAT can do the trick but the Flat files are huge and they sometimes contain special characters.

I need to filter out the records containing special characters from the file and also when the data type is not `int`.
Is there any way to do this in pig?
I am trying to find a substitute for `getType().getName()` kind of usage of java here.

Enforcing schema and using Describe is what we do while loading data and then remove the miss match but is there anyway to it without enforcing the schema.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Load the data into a line:charraray and use regular expression to filter out the records that contains characters other than numbers

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' AS (line:chararray);
B = FILTER A BY (line matches '\\d+$'); -- Change according to your needs.
DUMP B;
```